# EntityManagerFactory not found in JNDI Jboss Seam

Tags: jboss, seam, factory, entitymanager

I need help due to the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityManagerFactory not found in JNDI : java:/plugInEntityManagerFactory
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:247)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.initEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:79)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:21)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:125)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2082)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.unwrap(Component.java:2108)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1887)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1840)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1834)
        at com.medorder.mazama.WorkbenchIntegration.processRequests(WorkbenchIntegration.java:465)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:21)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:38)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:40)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:32)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:166)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:102)
        at com.medorder.mazama.WorkbenchIntegration_$$_javassist_2.processRequests(WorkbenchIntegration_$$_javassist_2.java)
        at service.PlugInHandler.accountRequest(PlugInHandler.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DefaultInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:220)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:408)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:272)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:189)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:85)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: plugInEntityManagerFactory not bound
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:296)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:243)
        ... 78 more
    11:43:53,411 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.identity
    11:43:53,412 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.web.session
    11:43:53,413 ERROR [SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityManagerFactory not found in JNDI : java:/plugInEntityManagerFactory
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:247)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.initEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:79)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:21)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:125)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2082)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.unwrap(Component.java:2108)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1887)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1840)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1834)
        at com.medorder.mazama.WorkbenchIntegration.processRequests(WorkbenchIntegration.java:465)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:21)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:38)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:40)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:32)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:166)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:102)
        at com.medorder.mazama.WorkbenchIntegration_$$_javassist_2.processRequests(WorkbenchIntegration_$$_javassist_2.java)
        at service.PlugInHandler.accountRequest(PlugInHandler.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DefaultInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:220)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:408)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:272)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:189)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:85)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: plugInEntityManagerFactory not bound
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:296)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:243)
        ... 78 more
```

To add here is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" 
        version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="CRMPlugin">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/CRMPluginDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <!--
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            -->
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/plugInEntityManagerFactory"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: On another note, i have created this project using New-Dynamic Web Project in eclipse

Comment: Did you reference this EntityManagerFactory in your components.xml? E.g. like this: <persistence:managed-persistence-context-name="entityManager" auto-create="true" persistence-unit-jndiname="java:/pluginEntityManagerFactory" />

Comment: yes i have done that as following <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
                                     auto-create="true"
                      persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/plugInEntityManagerFactory"/>

Answer (score 4):

Probably you generated the project with 2.2.2.Final, which is tailored for a fully compliant JEE5 environment (such as JBAS 5.1.0.GA), and are deploying on a non compliant environment (such as JBAS 4.2.x).

The fact is that in a JEE5 compliant environment, the `persistence.xml` file is searched by the JEE5 container (the server) and if found it is initialized and the entity manager factory is put in JNDI for you. A non compliant container does not deploy persistence contexts automatically so Seam is unable to find it in JNDI.

For this situation, Seam has a component that deploys the persistence context "by hand". Change your component definition with:

```
<persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="CRMPlugin" />
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" />
```

This way, the entity manager factory is created by Seam itself (not the container) and is not looked up in JNDI (and thus you don't use the `persistence-unit-jndi-name` parameter).

This is by the way the default `components.xml` generated by older versions of Seam, such as 2.2.0.GA, which are targeted at non-JEE5-compliant containers.

Comment: You saved me hours of work here, I have been struggling with this for days on a jboss5 to jboss7 application migration.  Just one thing, it's persistence-unit-name="CRMPlugin" (missing a dash).

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and Emir gave the tip and i wanted to post it here! I had to put the same name on persistence.xml[1] and components.xml[2] with a project named platto, so:

**[1]**

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/plattoEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

**[2]**

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true"  persistence-unit-jndi-name = "java:/plattoEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it ended up that I put the persistence.xml in the wrong directory.

So make sure you **put your persistence.xml in the META-INF folder!**
Either under your WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder if working directly in the webapp project or under /META-INF in the root of an embedded jar file (e.g. your ejb project)!

Answer (score 0):

So, I realize this a two year old thread, but I'm working on an "old" Seam/jBoss/Hibernate application doing some minor modifications and bumped into this problem. So maybe this will be useful to the next person in a similar situation.

I had the exact same error. My component.xml and persistence.xml where perfectly aligned.
Banged my head against this for a couple of days. Then I realized it had all started when I was adding some new fields to an Entity bean (I was interrupted for an urgency meeting by someone at work just after doing them and lost track of where I was). The Stack wasn't any help, so I removed the changes I'd made to the bean and eureka. So just go back to whatever your last changes to your entity beans where and check that they are compatible with your DB model. If something in the definition is off the EntityManager won't bind but the stack won't tell you what specific bean is causing the problem either. Maybe the Hibernate developers should take a look at improving this.

Cheers,